# jmeter distribution testing vs remote testing

Tags: jmeter

I searching about **Remote Execution** in **JMeter**. I see the `JMeter` website its official document says remote testing is good but I seeing **Distribution Testing pdf** also. What is the difference between both.

**NOTE :** And also  I am seeing the DistributorRunner and RemoteEngine in  jmeter_core package. It definitely says two type of testing in `JMeter` as **Remote and Distribution Testing**.

Please explain difference between `JMeter` **Distribute and Remote Testing**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jmeter "DistributedRunner" will be used to configure "remote servers". Please check details in jmeter source code [link](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/trunk/src/core/org/apache/jmeter/engine/DistributedRunner.java)

```
/**
 * This class serves all responsibility of starting and stopping distributed tests.
 * It was refactored from JMeter and RemoteStart classes to unify retry behavior.
 *
 * @see org.apache.jmeter.JMeter
 * @see org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.RemoteStart
 */
```